# Determinant of Stirling submatrix

Tags: recurrence-relations, determinant, stirling-numbers

Consider the table containing the Stirling numbers of the second kind
$S\left(  n,k\right)  $. From this table construct a square matrix $M$
containing $N$ differents rows from the table ($n_{1},\ldots,n_{N}$), and colums $1$ up to
$N$. So:

$$M = \begin{bmatrix} 
S\left(  n_{1},1\right)   & \ldots & S\left(  n_{1},N\right)  \\
\vdots &  & \vdots\\
S\left(  n_{N},1\right)   & \ldots & S\left(  n_{N},N\right)
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $n_{i}\in
%TCIMACRO{\U{2115} }
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{N}
%EndExpansion
_{0}$ and $n_{1}<n_{2}<\ldots<n_{N}$. Since $S\left(  n,1\right)=1$ if $n>0$ $M$ is equal to:

$$M = \begin{bmatrix} 
1   & \ldots & S\left(  n_{1},N\right)  \\
\vdots &  & \vdots\\
1  & \ldots & S\left(  n_{N},N\right)
\end{bmatrix}$$

An example of $M$ where $N=3$ and
$n=\left\{  1,3,5\right\}  $:

$$M_{ex} = \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 3 & 1\\
1 & 15 & 25
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $\det\left(  M_{ex}\right)  =60$.

My question is the following: Is there a known result that states that the
determinant of $M$ is always non-zero. If not, how would one go about in
showing this?

I suspect that one might somehow use either the explicit formula
$$S\left(  n,k\right) =\frac{1}{k!}\sum \limits_{j=0}^{k} \left(  -1\right)  ^{k-j}\binom{k}{j}j^{n}$$
or one of the (many) recursive relations
$$S\left(  n+1,k\right)=kS\left(  n,k\right)  +S\left(  n,k-1\right)$$
$$S\left(  n+1,k+1\right)=\sum \limits_{j=k}^{n} \binom{n}{j} = S\left(  j,k\right)$$

but I fail to see how.

Really appreciate any suggestions to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.